# C++ Merge sort check to see if a number is in the list

Tags: c++, mergesort

I have a merge sort program that I want to turn into a lottery game by having a user pick a number and then checking to see if the number is in the list and if it is they win. However i can't find any useful information on how to check the list for a certain number can some please explain to me how I would do that?

Comment: You can loop through the array to search for the value.

Comment: *"having a user pick a number"* - well, you'll need code to do that for starters. Then [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) seems reasonable to determine if said-value is in the sorted sequence, or [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) if the sequence is unsorted. Since your sort is O(nlogn), and `std::find` is O(n), i fail to see any usefulness for sorting in the first place if this is literally just a single-shot guess.

Comment: "I have a merge sort program that I want to turn into a lottery game" Or you could instead write a new program that is a lottery game. Depending on how you have structured your merge sort program, you may find it useful to re-use parts in the new program.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a mergesort but a bubblesort. To seach this list in an efficient way you can do a binary_search after you sort it, or you can do a linear search before you sort it.

The linear search will look like this:

```
bool found(int*a, const int N, const int TARGET)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    if(a[i] == TARGET)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Or, `return std::find(a, a+N, TARGET) != a+N;`